# Convert column value into CSV in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

Convert column value into CSV in SQL:

[image]

Comment: @Raunak, Please clarify which brand of RDBMS you are really using. You have tagged two different brands, mysql and postgresql. The solutions for your question will be different for each of these products, so you need to be specific to get the best answer.

Comment: Apologies, I am looking to achieve this in postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You need `string_agg`, So it should be something like [this](https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-string-agg/)-

```
SELECT 
    sr_number, name,
    string_agg(city, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city) AS city
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY 
    sr_number, name;
```